# tcpdump on interface when pinging nonexistent hosts on local network

Tags: linux, networking, ping, arp, icmp

I've statically configured the IP address of an interface on a server:

```
ip addr add 10.40.0.6/16 broadcast 10.40.255.255 dev eth1
```

If I try to ping a machine on the network (e.g., 10.40.0.1), it fails with "Destination Host Unreachable".

When the ping is running, if I do the following, I don't see any activity at all

```
tcpdump -i eth1 icmp
```

However, if I listen on the loopback interface instead:

```
tcpdump -i lo icmp
```

Then I see something like:

```
16:02:57.369632 IP 10.40.0.6 > 10.40.0.6: ICMP host 10.40.0.1 unreachable, length 92
```

My question is: why don't the ICMP packets show up as going out over the eth1 interface?

Edit:

```
# ip r ls
10.40.0.0/16 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.40.0.6
```

Comment: what does `ip r ls` say`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're pinging a non-existent host, then the ARP broadcast would fail. Tcpdump will never see icmp because eth1 won't send a unicast IP packet without a layer 2 destination.

Try this:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 arp
```

You should see the ARP resolution failing.

Comment: but why tcpdump show result in lo?

Comment: Because it's using icmp to report the ARP resolution failure. OP was capturing the failure report, not the ping.